# How to store information inside database

Tags: database

I have created an android application like oyo rooms to store information of my area but I don't know how to put data in database,because all the information can not be put inside the app so please help me to do so...

Comment: Did you ever use [google](https://google.com)?

Comment: Yes I have tried to find the answer but could not get specific one that's the reason I am asking

Comment: Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.